# How to return IEnumerable json array in a Http Post controller using .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I have the following dotnet core code and I'm trying to return a `TestResponse` JSON object that has a few nodes under it. However, using the return `Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(index => new Entities.TestResponse` call in the post return for some reason all the attributes of response are not found in the enclosure when clearly `Entities.TestResponse` has the response definition. I'm probably not configuring the `Enumerable` enclosure correctly. Does anyone know how to resolve this, so I can set the `response.result` & `response.exception` and return response JSON from my REST POST method?

```
namespace TestApi.Entities
{
    public class TestResponse 
    {
        public TestResponseNodes response { get; set; }
    }
    public class TestResponseNodes
    {
        public string result { get; set; }
        public string exception { get; set; }
    }
}

[HttpPost]
public Task<IEnumerable<Entities.TestResponse>> Post([FromBody] String input)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(index => new Entities.TestResponse
    {
        response.result = "No Error",
        response.exception = "None"
    }).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: What's the response you get when you call this API? Are you getting any error?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here, WebAPI automatically returns a 200 response code why aren't you just returning your data?

Comment: Also, why is this Async you do not use an await here?

Comment: The error is "The name 'response' does not exist in the current context." in the return Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Select(index => new Entities.TestResponse call. Maybe there's a better way to return the response. btw, I need specific json response per my design.

Comment: Your syntax is wrong, you need to also `new` up the inner object, it should be `new Entities.TestResponse { response = new Entities.TestResponseNodes { result = "No Error", exception = "None" } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, you need to also `new` up the inner object, for example:

```
new Entities.TestResponse
{
    response = new Entities.TestResponseNodes 
    {
        result = "No Error", 
        exception = "None" 
    } 
}
```

As an aside, you should follow common C# conventions and capitalise your property names, for example:

```
public class TestResponse
{
    public TestResponseNodes Response;
}
public class TestResponseNodes
{
    public string Result { get; set; }
    public string Exception { get; set; }
}
```